# MyAuth Laravel bundle error on login

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-3

I'm using MyAuth bundle as my authentication platform. All is okay except I'm having trouble when I want to sign in. It keeps telling me that I have entered an incorrect username or password. But I have no problem to sign up.

Here's the Login controller (user.php):

```
    public function action_login(){

    // get login POST data
    $userdata = array(
        'username'      => Input::get('email'),
        'password'      => Input::get('password')
    );

    if ( Auth::attempt($userdata) ){
        // we are now logged in, go to dashboard

        if(Config::get('myauth::config.login_redirect') != ''){
            $redirect_url = Config::get('myauth::config.login_redirect');
        } else {
            $redirect_url = Config::get('myauth::config.bundle_route') . '/dashboard';
        }

        return Redirect::to($redirect_url);
    } else {
        // auth failure! redirect to login with errors
        $redirect_url = Config::get('myauth::config.bundle_route') . '/' . Config::get('myauth::config.login_route');
        return Redirect::to($redirect_url)->with('notification', 'Incorrect login or password');
    }

}
```

Here's my view:

```
    {{ Form::open(Config::get('myauth::config.bundle_route') . '/' . Config::get('myauth::config.login_route')) }}
    <!-- check for login errors flash var -->
    @if (Session::has('notification'))
        <span class="notification">{{ Session::get('notification') }}</span>
    @endif

    <!-- email field -->
    <p>{{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}</p>
    <p>{{ Form::text('email') }}</p>

    <!-- password field -->
    <p>{{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}</p>
    <p>{{ Form::password('password') }}</p>

    <!-- submit button -->
    <p>{{ Form::submit('Login') }}</p>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Here's my auth.php:

```
return array(

    'driver' => 'eloquent',

    'username' => 'username',

    'password' => 'password',

    'model' => 'User',

    'table' => 'users',

);
```

And the database:

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I've asked this question in Laravel forums, but still couldn't find any answers. Is there any fault on the varchar number or something on variables?

I never change any other settings. Could someone please find what's the problem in this code? Thanks

Comment: Please also share your user model, should be in `application/models/user.php`

Comment: Here it is @PhillSparks `<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

}`

Comment: Your `varchar` looks fine, it only needs to be 60 long to hold a password hash.  Did you use the signup route from MyAuth to create your user account?  Or did you create the user account by your own code?

Comment: @PhillSparks I did it with MyAuth. I guess I'll just have to revamp all of it. Thanks anyway